# Context this problem in fragments Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello everyone I have problem with code that I find in internet.
Many times when I want to apply code from internet to my app I have problem with one thing "this"

there is a example

listview.adapter = Adapter(this, R.layout.tescik,list)

every time that I paste code to fragment I have red lined "this" and i really dont know how to fix it, I cant find the solution.
Can anyone help me how to fix this (heh) problem?

there is is my code where i try to implement it.

```
package com.example.darwinaapp.podstrony

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ListView
import com.example.darwinaapp.Adapter
import com.example.darwinaapp.Model
import com.example.darwinaapp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_promocje.*

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"


class Promocje : Fragment() {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)


        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        var listview = lista
        var list = mutableListOf<Model>()

        list.add(Model("Maravedi", "Bardzo dobre winko", R.drawable.heroesmerlot))
        list.add(Model("Maravedi", "Bardzo dobre winko", R.drawable.heroesmerlot))
        list.add(Model("Maravedi", "Bardzo dobre winko", R.drawable.heroesmerlot))

//There is my problem
        listview.adapter = Adapter(this, R.layout.tescik,list)
//There is my problem

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promocje, container, false)
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            Promocje().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use there `requireContext()` .

```
 listview.adapter = Adapter(requireContext(), R.layout.tescik,list)
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to pass the context to the adapter, because you can get context from
the view group of createViewHolder(parent:ViewGroup, viewType:Int)

and in onBindViewHolder, you can get context from itemView.context